# wrong number of type arguments c++ to java code

Tags: java, c++

I am currently converting C++ code to Java.. I need help on converting it can't find something on google the can help me.. I am trying to have a Java code on this problem 
( https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/alphabetical-numbers/ )

C++ Code
        TreeMap m = new TreeMap();

while ( dataset-- ) 
        map ::iterator it;
        string str [20];

```
    while ( cin >> input && input ) 
        for ( it = m.begin (); it != m.end (); it++ ) 
            if ( (*it).second == input )
                str [index++] = (*it).first;

    for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < index; j++ ) 
            if ( str [i] > str [j] )
                swap (str [i], str [j]);  
    cout << m [str [0]];
    for ( int i = 1; i < index; i++ )
        cout << " " << m [str [i]];
    cout << endl;
```

And this is the Java Code that i have converted..
        TreeMap m = new TreeMap();

```
   while ((dataset--) != 0)

        Iterator<String, Integer> it;
        String[] str = new String[20];
        while ((input == Boolean.parseBoolean(true).leghth() > 0))

                   for(it = m.firstKey(); it.hasNext();)

                        Map.Entry<String, Integer> current = it.next();
            if (current.getValue() == input)

                str [index++] = current.getKey();

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)

        for (int j = i + 1; j < index; j++)

            if (str [i].compareTo(str [j]) > 0)

                swap(str [i], str [j]);
```

Comment: `Iterator` takes only one argument. I think you mean `Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`

Comment: Also, this expression `(input == Boolean.parseBoolean(true).leghth() > 0)` looks very suspicious

Comment: I'm just trying to convert the code to java.. I don't know what wrong on it :3

Comment: The way to convert code between languages is *not* to try and do it line by line. The *correct* way is to 1) know both programming languages well. 2) know what the code being converted does. 3) write new code in the target language that does the same as the original - that new code may look completely different from the original if the languages are sufficiently different. Remember that code that *looks* the same may still be semantically very different in two languages.